# How to set max-source-rows-allowed Teiid Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, teiid

While scouting the documentation we found the following properties that we want to set.

- max-source-rows-allowed
- exception-on-max-source-rows

Found on the following page:
https://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/16.0.x/content/admin/Other_Considerations.html

However, we have tried several ways to set these without avail. The properties are not listed on the following page.
https://github.com/teiid/teiid-spring-boot/blob/master/docs/Reference.adoc

How can we set these properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teiid spring boot does not currently allow setting properties like these, which are normally set in the Teiid WildFly subsystem, in an elegant way.  The only workaround is to wire in your own EmbeddedConfiguration with all the appropriate settings - as the TeiidAutoConfiguration logic won't make any additional changes to a supplied configuration.

You can also log an issue / supply a patch to have this properties set from the configuration file.